# Ubuntu 16.04 detect/confirm raid0

Tags: ubuntu, raid-0

How to detect that i have raid0?

I have created hardware raid0, but want to confirm in inside Ubuntu, that Ubuntu is using that raid0 instead of software one...

How to detect both hardware and software raid0 in Ubuntu?

Thank you.

```
root@beck:/opt# dmraid -s
*** Group superset isw_dgebhgddbf
--> Active Subset
name   : isw_dgebhgddbf_Beck
size   : 468873728
stride : 64
type   : stripe
status : ok
subsets: 0
devs   : 2
spares : 0
root@beck:/opt# dmraid -r
/dev/sdb: isw, "isw_dgebhgddbf", GROUP, ok, 234441646 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sda: isw, "isw_dgebhgddbf", GROUP, ok, 234441646 sectors, data@ 0

root@beck:/opt# df -h
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                              3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                             795M  9,5M  786M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/isw_dgebhgddbf_Beck2  212G  5,0G  196G   3% /
tmpfs                             3,9G  116M  3,8G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                             3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/isw_dgebhgddbf_Beck1  511M  3,6M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                             795M  112K  795M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: And how did you create this "hardware" raid0?

Comment: When booting pc via ctrl+i if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: That's not hardware raid, it's fakeraid.

Comment: What do you mean? Which one is fake? The one that Ubuntu created or the one i created at startup via ctrl+i?

Comment: Yes, it's [fakeraid](http://skrypuch.com/raid/). Pop that into your favorite search engine to learn more about it.

Comment: The problem is that i have erased windows 10 and installed Ubuntu. On windows i had about 1gb/sec and here i have 600mb/sec. I guess it's not working in raid0 or it's working, but very badly and in software mode...

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the RAID in hardware it will be mostly invisible to Ubuntu. That means it will probably named `sda` or so. The real harddrives are usually not visible anymore. If that is the case it means that it is probably a hardware RAID.

If you use software RAID you must have a device called `md0` or with another number. If your partition resides on that it probably is a software RAID.

Comment: i'm trying to get info from dmraid, it says that i have some kind of raid, but can't understand what type of raid it is and whether it is software or hardware

Comment: It says type: striped. That means RAID 0

Comment: And yes you are using your fake RAID. It is not Linux Software RAID. But not quite Hardware RAID either. And please be advised that with RAID 0 you will have 0 redunancy. If one drive fails you will lose ALL your data.

Comment: Any ideas why it's so slow? Should be at least 1gb/sec, but having only around 600~mb/sec by the looks of the benchmarks... ugh

Comment: I have no Idea but the raid is okay.

Comment: The slowness could be due to it being fake raid. Linux native software raid might be faster.